# Nested list to string and join each line

Tags: python, list

I want to generate a multiline textfile out of an export i had several problems with ´dict_value´ but solved it, now I want to join every object in new line as string.

List:

```
a = [[1,'b','c'],[2,'d','e'],[3,'f','g']]  
list(map('\n'.join,a))
```

but i got the error:

> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

The Output should be:

```
1,b,c
2,d,e
3,f,g
```

as a string

I tried it with `list(map('\n'.join,map(str, a))` but the output was

> ["[\n1\n,\n \n'\nb\n'\n,\n \n'\nc\n'\n]", "[\n2\n,\n \n'\nd\n'\n,\n
>   \n'\ne\n'\n]", "[\n3\n,\n \n'\nf\n'\n,\n \n'\ng\n'\n]"]

any ideas or solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join each sublist by a comma, and join each resultant of that join with a newline:

```
res = '\n'.join(','.join(str(i) for i in x) for x in a)

print(res)
```

Result:

```
1,b,c
2,d,e
3,f,g
```